# Connect Android device to Macbook hotspot (via Wifi)

Tags: android, macbook, hotspot, internet-sharing

There is a way to connect an android device (Lollipop 5.1) to a Macbook hotspot (via Wifi)?  I have set up the internet sharing on my Mac, and now other devices are successfully connected, except my android device, which stay on "obtaining IP address".

I have tried without success adding security to the connection (WEP) and setting a 13 characters password as suggested in other sites, but the android device still stay without internet connection.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a static IP worked for me:

1. Share your Macbook internet connection without a password (No security).
2. Connect your android device to that network (It should get your device connected but it will never get an IP, so far...)
3. Select on your android device with a long press your new Wifi connection and then > `Modify network`.
4. Select on "ipv4 Settings" > `Static IP`
5. Set as your IP: `192.168.2.4`    and your Gateway as: `192.168.2.1`

An that's all.  If more devices will be connected you should change the last digit of the IP address for each new device with consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Sync from the Mac computer with the Android phone and back again using the app SyncMate.

Download the best way to [connect an android phone to mac](https://www.sync-mac.com/sync-android-phones.html) and you can easily do Sync Mac with Android and iOS devices, Sync with MTP, address book sync and calendars.